# Why does this php query prints nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code, which is supposed to get the "first" and "last" values of the column where the "id" matches what is in the URL.  For instance, when the URL is `../Profile?id=1`, it would say `First: Bob Last: Doe`, because `Bob Doe` is attached to the `id of 1`.

I do this with the following code:

```
session_start();
$id = $_GET['search'];
$dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost", "SocialAdmin", "******") 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");       
$selected = mysql_select_db("socialdonuttesting",$dbhandle)     
    or die("Could not select database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
$first = $result['first'];
$last = $result['last'];
echo "First: $first Last: $last";
```

But for some reason, this is just displaying `First: Last:` when I go to `../Profile?id=1`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Just to discard the obvious: Have you tried to run your query directly in MySQL shell and checked that the record exists?

Comment: @Barranka Yes, and the record *does* exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not fetching the result.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['first'];
echo $row['last'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php
However, drop the mysql_ usage and go with PDO.
Also, you are vulnerable to sql injection in your example.

Comment: I am aware of this, I am going to use that once the site goes public; I'm just making sure everything works as-is.

Answer (score 0):

you are not fetching you query

try this

```
 session_start();
 $id = $_GET['search'];
 $dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost", "SocialAdmin", "******") 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");       
 $selected = mysql_select_db("socialdonuttesting",$dbhandle)     
 or die("Could not select database");
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $first = $row['first'];
 $last = $row['last'];
 echo "First: ". $first. " Last: ". $last ."</ br>"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$result` is a resource, you have to use `mysql_fetch_*` functions. In addittion, I don't recommend you to use * in your SQL query (for example, if you change table structure in the future, the results will be messed up.